# npm run build works fine on local machine but shows error on remote ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, devops, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my MERN app on the digital ocean remote ubuntu server. After git clone, I did npm install to my root folder, client folder, and server folder. But when I tried to run npm start from the root folder then only the server app was running and an error came on the client-side. So I did cd into the client folder and tried the command npm run build (which I did on my local machine as well and the optimized build got created successfully) but it showed the below error on the remote server

```
> client@0.1.0 build /home/nishant/apps/rentaporta/client
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nishant/.npm/_logs/2020-10-27T05_22_30_755Z-debug.log
```

I deleted node_modules, package-lock.json, and tried the npm ci command as well but there was no improvement. My folder structure is

```
root
 client
 server
```

Below is my package.json script in root folder

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "server-install": "npm install ---prefix server",
    "server": "npm start --prefix server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "build-client": "npm run build --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "npm run server-install & concurrently \"npm run build-client\"  \"npm run server\""
  },
```

Please, someone, help me. If you need more explanation I'm ready to put more details as needed.

Comment: Check node version

Comment: node --version
v12.19.0

Comment: Use `top` to find the memory usage when running `npm install`. This might be something to do with the amount of memory available.

Comment: Indeed it was a memory issue. The swap memory was 0 in my ubuntu remote server. Thank you @bitsapien.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally, I figured out the problem. My remote ubuntu server had 1GB ram but there was no swap memory. I used the command sudo free -h, and found swap memory was 0. So, I followed this article (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) to create the swap memory, and finally, my app got deployed.

Also, cd into your client folder and run this command in the terminal-

```
$ export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```

Comment: How much swap value did you set?